# Tracking Facebook Mobile Installs on iOS

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, mixpanel

I'm using the facebook iOS SDK for tracking:

```
[FBSettings publishInstall:APP_ID];
```

but would like to know *if* the current user was indeed an install from facebook for our internal metrics and retention.  The data is showing up properly on facebook's site, but we'd like to integrate more fine-tuned data into mixpanel.

Comment: Did you ever get an answer to this? I would like the same information for integrating with mixpanel

Comment: Unfortunately not :'-(